# How to add readable (r) to a string?

Tags: python

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaJVm.png)

I have issues using the path of my file because it contains `\` so I'm obliged to either add `r` or swap the `\` with double `\`.

The problem is that I want to add the `r` to a string stored in a variable without doing it manually (I get the variable which contains the path with an `input()`). How could I do that?

EDIT : Here is the code :

```
#The path of my directory
direc =str(input())
list = os.listdir(direc) #This gives me the name of all the files in my directory

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(the path of my directory \list[0]) #path of the file, this is where I have trouble
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(length)
```

Comment: I think you should provide an example code. `Input()` function dosen't need it.

Comment: 1. The `r` is a piece of syntax for a string literal. The string object does not have or not have an `r`, so you can't add one.

Comment: 2. If you input a string with `input` you shouldn't have to escape anything.

Comment: thanks for the edit btw I'm new to the site

Comment: From your code it's still not clear exactly what you're doing or what problem you're having. What code do you actually have where you have written `the path of my directory \list[0]` ?

Comment: I have something like "C:\Users\Movie" and I want to add \NameOfTheMovie.mp4 which is the content of list[0]. I get that but the result of cv2.VideoCapute function is false. However, when I manually write the path with r before I get the right result.

Comment: Please show your code that doesn't work in your question, as text. Do not post pictures of your code.

Comment: Can you print the output of direct and liste as text if possible? It will bring more clarity